# Run a visual studio 2010 Windows7 project on a Windows XP machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp, compatibility

I have created a simple windows forms visual studio 2010 project in windows 7 32 Bit.

I need to run the .exe file in the release folder under windows xp.

What files to I need to bundle with my EXE to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well need the [Visual Studio 2010 redsitributables](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: You need to run it on the target machine.  I simply include it with my installer and run it post install.  I'm sure newer InstallShields will do this for you.

Comment: It is working almost fine....when I click .exe file and select run as administrator....It says Run time environment has not found....If I double click it works fine...Bet I need administrator privilege...(I have tested in windows XP)

Comment: Yup, I'm guessing you need to have administrative rights to install this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything extra. You just need to be sure if required .NET Framework is installed on the target platform which is XP in this case. Other than that, I suggest you to use Visual Studio's Package and Deployment Wizard to make a setup. But even without Package and Deployment Wizard, if you use release output (not debug), just copying executable should be enough to run on XP platform. Be sure that you don't use anything unsupported by Windows XP (like DirectX 11, Direct2d etc.).

p.s: you may need some additional files like manifest files. but that completely depends on your project. Package and Deployment Wizard should take care of these as well.